# Can't not backup via google drive, google one and adb commend line

Tags: android, backup

I am trying to backup my phone via google drive, google one and adb but none of those works, back up button for google drive and google one just simply grey out.

And adb just give me these errors:

```
raphael:/ $ bmgr backupnow --all
Running incremental backup for all packages.
Package @pm@ with result: Transport error
Backup finished with result: Transport error
raphael:/ $ bmgr backupnow appdata
Running incremental backup for 1 requested packages.
Package appdata with result: Package not found
Backup finished with result: Success
```

Does anyone know how to fix that?